# how to embed partial view only displayable if some condition met

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a partial view named Posted. I want that partial view to be displayed when user do some activity on my main view(clicking on submit button.)

My partial view is following

```
@using WebApplication1.Models
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Posted";
 }

<h2>Posted</h2>

@foreach (Data d in ViewBag.Data)
{
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="@d.b64" style="width:200px;height:100px" /></td>
        <td><span>@d.bio</span></td>
        <td>@d.url</td>
    </tr>
</table>

 }
```

My partial view resides inside index view. When I ran the app, threw error `Null Exception` exception

My question is how I can place a partial view that only appears when user clicks on submit button on main view (containing view of partial/child view,`Posted` view in my case)?

Following is my code in index View

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Posted", "Home"))
{
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">Cat</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.catid, (SelectList)ViewBag.cats, null, new { @class = "dropdown" })

    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">Pass</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.password)
    </div>
</div>

 <input type="submit" value="Click to View" />

}
```

And following is my code in Posted Action method

```
   public ActionResult Posted(int cat) {
        var v = from c in
                    done.s1
                where c.catid==cat
                select c;

        List<Models.Data> data = new List<Models.Data>();
        foreach(s1 s in v)
        {
            var img = Models.StringCipher.DecryptImage( s.us,"abc");
            var str = Convert.ToBase64String(img);
            str = "data:image/png;base64," + str;
            string bio1 = Models.StringCipher.Decrypt(s.bio, "abc");
            string url1 = Models.StringCipher.Decrypt(s.url, "abc");

            data.Add(new Models.Data() { us=null, b64=str,url=url1,bio=bio1 });
        }
        ViewBag.data = data;
        return View("Posted");
    }
```

The `Posted` View appears when user select cat from dropdownlist and click submit button.

Comment: Unclear what your asking. What is the code in the POST method that your submitting to? Are you returning a view or redirecting? And why are you using `@foreach (Data d in ViewBag.Data)` - if `Data` is `null`, you will get an exception

Comment: @StephenMuecke In Index View I have form and submit button, clicking on it will display `Posted` View by doing "return View("Posted")"

Comment: So what is the code in your `Index` view to show the partial? And have you assigned a value to `ViewBag.Data`, and where? You need to give more context in your question.

Comment: `ViewBag.data` in the controller and `ViewBag.Data` in the view :) STOP using `ViewBag` and use view models

Comment: @StephenMuecke my data is a collection, not just one object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117523/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-alex).